# Float blocks of text over images in left and right columns

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to recreate the attached screen shot in wordpress and I'm having some css issues.

[image]

As you can see there are two columns with very simular content.

At present I have got this far:

```css
 .race-tri {
   width: 570px;
   position: relative;
 }
 .banner_txt {
   width: 250px;
   background: #F08E03;
   padding: 5px 15px;
   color: #ffffff;
   position: absolute;
   top: 150px;
   left: 0;
 }
 .race-tri h3 {
   text-transform: uppercase;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
   font-weight: 800;
 }
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align:center;">RACES</h1>

<div class="race-bar-text">
  <div style="float:left; width:570px; box-sizing:border-box;">
    <p>Throughout the year Tri Team Glos runs various events, notably the TTG Gloucester Triathlon and the TTG Newent Duathlon.</p>
    <p>Our Triathlon is a pool based Sprint race with a 400m Swim and a two lap 28km bike course finished off with a 6km run and will take place on Sunday 29th May 2016.</p>
  </div>
  <div style="float:right; width:570px; box-sizing:border-box;">
    <p>Our duathlon comprises a 5k run, 18k bike and 5k run. Next year's event will take place on 3rd April 2016,</p>
    <p>For those wishing to enter the Tri Team Glos' Children's Race, please <a href="#" target="blank">click here.</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="race-tri">
  <img src="http://staging-triteamglos.transitiongraphics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/img2.png">
  <div class="banner_txt">
    <h3>Glocester triathlon</h3>
    <span class="race-date">May 25th, 2016</span>
    <span class="race-type">Triathlon</span>
    <p>Swim: 1km
      <br>Bikd: 20km
      <br>Run: 5km</p>
  </div>
  <a class="btn">ENTER EVENT</a>
  <a class="btn" style="float:right;">MORE INFORMATION</a>
</div>

<div class="race-tri" style="float: right;">
  <img src="http://staging-triteamglos.transitiongraphics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/img-3.jpg">
  <div class="banner_txt">
    <h3>Newent Duathlon</h3>
    <span class="race-date">April 16th, 2017 (TBC)</span>
    <span class="race-type">Duathlon</span>
    <p>Swim: 1km
      <br>Bikd: 20km
      <br>Run: 5km</p>
  </div>
  <a class="btn">ENTER EVENT</a>
  <a class="btn" style="float:right;">MORE INFORMATION</a>
</div>
```

Ignoring the main background image and some the smaller styling issues, I am having issues floating the two blocks side by side, whilst floating the inner orange text block.

I thought I could achieve this by making the background relative and then the inner text block absolute. Hoping it would be absolute within the block, not the page.

Many thanks in adavance for suggestions.

Comment: Indeed...this should be managed as two separate rows/columns etc.

Comment: One container, 2 sub container with float then clear..

Comment: you may want to look at flexbox to get you the desired look which will enable you to not have to float stuff

Answer (score 0):

@Dhaval Chheda recommended looking at flexboxes, which I'd recommend too - they'd be a better way to get what you're looking for.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

[See this link](https://gyazo.com/7f355906b6a68299cb55650368051930) for a way to divvy up the structure of the blocks, and [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6196b8xy/1/) for it in action. This way you'll be able to have some more precise control over the layout of the page.